# Why do people from Rome use "a" when criticism is involved?

Tags: regional, exclamations

When I stay in Rome I hear people using "a" in a strange way, especially in cases in which a criticism or an insult is involved.

For example:

> ***a*** vedi questo
>
> ***a*** burino
>
> ***a*** st***zo

and so on.

Can anyone explain what the reason and the historical origin of that “a” are? And, also, what does it precisely mean?

Comment: In the first example, it is actually “anvedi”, and I am not sure it is the same as the general “a”. According to Ravaro's *Dizionario romanesco*, it derives from Latin *an videas*.

Answer (score 15):

Si tratta di un vocativo, e non è necessariamente limitato a degli insulti.

[Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatica_del_dialetto_romanesco), ad esempio, cita:

> Ah Varte', ando vai?

che possiamo rendere con

> Ehi Walter, dove vai?

Altri esempi si possono trovare su questa pagina di [Roma virtuale](http://roma.andreapollett.com/S8/dialett3.htm)

Ad esempio

> A rega',...

ossia

> Ragazzi,...

Il [vocativo in italiano](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/vocativo_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) è probabilmente meno usato, ed è reso in varie forme con il [complemento di vocazione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/complemento-di-vocazione_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/)

Answer (score 3):

It is simply an interjection, the Roman exactly corresponding to Tuscan – and so Italian – “[o](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/o2/)”, which strengthens an exclamation that follows (not to be confused with “[oh](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/oh/)”).

Answer (score 3):

Il valore vocativo è stato ottimamente illustrato da nico.

Per maggiore informazione vorrei solo aggiungere che:

> When I stay **in Rome** I hear people using

a) - non è uso dei **soli romani**: questa variante dell'o vocativo si può sentire in gran parte dell'Italia meridionale, da  Napoli: *"a 'nfame!*" a tutta la Puglia: *"a ricchio'..."*

> **specially** in cases in which a criticism or an insult is involved.

b) -  non è particolarmente dovuto ad una ingiuria: *'a more'...*", *"a Nando*", *"a *tutta bbona!"*, "*a strafica*!", *"a paraculo!"*

c) infine una forma di interiezione vocativa è presente in **tutta Italia**, con leggere varianti:

a Firenze è rimasto il classico 'o' : *"o ragazzi"*, al sud *"a raga'.."*, al Nord 'oè, ué': *"uè ragasi"*, a Milano: : *"oè pirla!*", a Bologna :  "*oè ragassuolo"* etc...

d) infine "**a vedi questo"** è errato e non è assimilabile al vocativo.
la forma corretta è " .*.'anvedi* 'sto fijode..." ed è una deformazione di: *"non/ma vedi 'sto..."*

Comment: Ottime puntualizzazioni. Ti vorrei solo chiedere qual è la tua fonte per il fatto che “anvedi” derivi da “non vedi” (cf. anche quello che scrivevo in un commento alla domanda).